# how to find what script applies to certain elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any way to find out what script applies to certain HTML elements?
With inspect element you can see the styles applied to elements and I'd like to check what javascript is applied also.

Example(this is what actually made me ask the question):

http://yeti.wp.irishmiss.com/album-gallery/

When you hover an item, a few things are happening and I'd like to know witch script(there are many scripts included in the html page) is responsible for the effects, and if all the scripts were merged into one .js file, would be nice to know the code responsible for the effect.

There are a lot of scripts and would be nice to know witch does certain things to the html elements.

Comment: You can look for functions bound to the element (onclick, etc). Is there something in particular you're trying to find? If so, please supply an example.

Comment: What script? Are you talking about event handlers?

Comment: In Chrome you can view event listeners in the dev tools pane. Right-click on the page, then click "inspect element". At the top right is a tab for Event Listeners.

Comment: @A. Wolff I edited the post and posted an example

Comment: @gtr1971 I posted an example. Everything in the Event Listeners points to jquery.js and that's not helping....